# GetWindowLongPtr crash in windows 8 and windows 10

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have written an application which hosts a webbrowser inside a hwnd window. In windows 7 64 bits everything runs perfectly. Unfortunately, in windows 8 and windows 10 the application crashes. I found a line which crashes the application could you please lead me to why does it crash?

```
ExternalDispatch *m_external = myHost->getDispatch();
m_external->AddRef();

result = EmbedBrowserObject(hwnd, m_external);
if (result)  {
    return(-1);
}
```

Then this code is called from a function that obtains the webbrowser2 object.

```
IOleObject* browserObject;
IWebBrowser2* webBrowser2;

browserObject = *((IOleObject**)GetWindowLongPtr(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA));
browserObject->lpVtbl->QueryInterface(browserObject, &IID_IWebBrowser2,
        (void**)&webBrowser2));


long WINAPI EmbedBrowserObject( HWND hwnd, void* externalDispatch )
{
    IOleObject* browserObject;
    IWebBrowser2* webBrowser2;
    RECT rect;
    register char* ptr;
    register _IOleClientSiteEx* _iOleClientSiteEx;

    // Our IOleClientSite, IOleInPlaceSite, and IOleInPlaceFrame functions need to
    // get our window handle. We
    // could store that in some global. But then, that would mean that our
    // functions would work with only that
    // one window. If we want to create multiple windows, each hosting its own
    // browser object (to display its
    // own web page), then we need to create unique IOleClientSite,
    // IOleInPlaceSite, and IOleInPlaceFrame
    // structs for each window. And we'll put an extra member at the end of those
    // structs to store our extra
    // data such as a window handle. So, our functions won't have to touch global
    // data, and can therefore be
    // re-entrant and work with multiple objects/windows.
    //
    // Remember that a pointer to our IOleClientSite we create here will be passed
    // as the first arg to every
    // one of our IOleClientSite functions. Ditto with the IOleInPlaceFrame object
    // we create here, and the
    // IOleInPlaceFrame functions. So, our functions are able to retrieve the
    // window handle we'll store here,
    // and then, they'll work with all such windows containing a browser control.
    //
    // Furthermore, since the browser will be calling our IOleClientSite's
    // QueryInterface to get a pointer to
    // our IOleInPlaceSite and IDocHostUIHandler objects, that means that our
    // IOleClientSite QueryInterface
    // must have an easy way to grab those pointers. Probably the easiest thing to
    // do is just embed our
    // IOleInPlaceSite and IDocHostUIHandler objects inside of an extended
    // IOleClientSite which we'll call
    // a _IOleClientSiteEx. As long as they come after the pointer to the
    // IOleClientSite VTable, then we're
    // ok.
    //
    // Of course, we need to GlobalAlloc the above structs now. We'll just get all
    // 3 with a single call to
    // GlobalAlloc, especially since they're are contained inside of our
    // _IOleClientSiteEx anyway.
    //
    // So, we're not actually allocating separate IOleClientSite, IOleInPlaceSite,
    // IOleInPlaceFrame and
    // IDocHostUIHandler structs.
    //
    // One final thing. We're going to allocate extra room to store the pointer to
    // the browser object.
    if ( !( ptr = (char*)GlobalAlloc( GMEM_FIXED, sizeof( _IOleClientSiteEx ) + sizeof( IOleObject* ) ) ) )
        return ( -1 );

    // Initialize our IOleClientSite object with a pointer to our IOleClientSite
    // VTable.
    _iOleClientSiteEx = (_IOleClientSiteEx*)( ptr + sizeof( IOleObject* ) );
    _iOleClientSiteEx->client.lpVtbl = &MyIOleClientSiteTable;

    // Initialize our IOleInPlaceSite object with a pointer to our IOleInPlaceSite
    // VTable.
    _iOleClientSiteEx->inplace.inplace.lpVtbl = &MyIOleInPlaceSiteTable;

    // Initialize our IOleInPlaceFrame object with a pointer to our
    // IOleInPlaceFrame VTable.
    _iOleClientSiteEx->inplace.frame.frame.lpVtbl = &MyIOleInPlaceFrameTable;

    // Save our HWND (in the IOleInPlaceFrame object) so our IOleInPlaceFrame
    // functions can retrieve it.
    _iOleClientSiteEx->inplace.frame.window = hwnd;

    // Initialize our IDocHostUIHandler object with a pointer to our
    // IDocHostUIHandler VTable.
    _iOleClientSiteEx->ui.ui.lpVtbl = &MyIDocHostUIHandlerTable;
    _iOleClientSiteEx->ui.externalDispatch = (IDispatch*)externalDispatch;

    // Get a pointer to the browser object and lock it down (so it doesn't
    // "disappear" while we're using
    // it in this program). We do this by calling the OS function
    // CoCreateInstance().
    //
    // NOTE: We need this pointer to interact with and control the browser. With
    // normal WIN32 controls such as a
    // Static, Edit, Combobox, etc, you obtain an HWND and send messages to it
    // with SendMessage(). Not so with
    // the browser object. You need to get a pointer to it. This object contains
    // an array of pointers to functions           // you can call within the
    // browser object. Actually, it contains a 'lpVtbl' member that is a pointer
    // to that
    // array. We call the array a 'VTable'.
    //
    // For example, the browser object happens to have a SetClientSite() function
    // we want to call. So, after we
    // retrieve the pointer to the browser object (in a local we'll name
    // 'browserObject'), then we can call that
    // function, and pass it args, as so:
    //
    // browserObject->lpVtbl->SetClientSite(browserObject, SomeIOleClientObject);
    //
    // There's our pointer to the browser object in 'browserObject'. And there's
    // the pointer to the browser object's
    // VTable in 'browserObject->lpVtbl'. And the pointer to the SetClientSite
    // function happens to be stored in a
    // member named 'SetClientSite' within the VTable. So we are actually
    // indirectly calling SetClientSite by using
    // a pointer to it. That's how you use a VTable.

    // Get Internet Explorer's IWebBrowser2 object (ie, IE's main object)
    if ( !CoCreateInstance( &CLSID_WebBrowser, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC, &IID_IWebBrowser2,
                            (void**)&webBrowser2 ) ) {
        browserObject = 0;

        // We need to get a pointer to IWebBrowser2's IOleObject child object
        webBrowser2->lpVtbl->QueryInterface( webBrowser2, &IID_IOleObject,
                                             (void**)&browserObject );

        // Ok, we now have the pointer to the IOleObject child object in
        // 'browserObject'. Let's save this in the
        // memory block we allocated above, and then save the pointer to that whole
        // thing in our window's
        // USERDATA member. That way, if we need multiple windows each hosting its
        // own browser object, we can
        // call EmbedBrowserObject() for each one, and easily associate the
        // appropriate browser object with
        // its matching window and its own objects containing per-window data.
        if ( ( *( (IOleObject**)ptr ) = browserObject ) ) {
            SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)ptr );

            // Give the browser a pointer to my IOleClientSite object.
            //
            // NOTE: We pass our _IOleClientSiteEx struct and lie -- saying that it's
            // a IOleClientSite. It's ok. A
            // _IOleClientSiteEx struct starts with an embedded IOleClientSite. So the
            // browser won't care, and we want
            // this extended struct passed to our IOleClientSite functions.
            if ( !browserObject->lpVtbl->SetClientSite(
                      browserObject, (IOleClientSite*)_iOleClientSiteEx ) ) {
                // Set the display area of our browser control the same as our window's
                // size
                // and actually put the browser object into our window.
                GetClientRect( hwnd, &rect );
                if ( !browserObject->lpVtbl->DoVerb(
                          browserObject, OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE, 0,
                          (IOleClientSite*)_iOleClientSiteEx, 0, hwnd, &rect ) ) {
                    // Let's call several functions in the IWebBrowser2 object to position
                    // the browser display area
                    // in our window. The functions we call are put_Left(), put_Top(),
                    // put_Width(), and put_Height().
                    // Note that we reference the IWebBrowser2 object's VTable to get
                    // pointers to those functions. And
                    // also note that the first arg we pass to each is the pointer to the
                    // IWebBrowser2 object.
                    webBrowser2->lpVtbl->put_Left( webBrowser2, 0 );
                    webBrowser2->lpVtbl->put_Top( webBrowser2, 0 );
                    webBrowser2->lpVtbl->put_Width( webBrowser2, rect.right );
                    webBrowser2->lpVtbl->put_Height( webBrowser2, rect.bottom );

                    // We no longer need the IWebBrowser2 object (ie, we don't plan to
                    // call any more functions in it
                    // right now, so we can release our hold on it). Note that we'll still
                    // maintain our hold on the
                    // browser IOleObject until we're done with that object.
                    webBrowser2->lpVtbl->Release( webBrowser2 );

                    // Success
                    return ( 0 );
                }
            }

            webBrowser2->lpVtbl->Release( webBrowser2 );

            // Something went wrong setting up the browser!
            UnEmbedBrowserObject( hwnd );
            return ( -4 );
        }

        webBrowser2->lpVtbl->Release( webBrowser2 );

        GlobalFree( ptr );

        // Can't create an instance of the browser!
        return ( -3 );
    }

        GlobalFree( ptr );
        enter code here
        // Can't get the web browser's IWebBrowser2!
        return ( -2 );
    }
```

Comment: Can you refer us to the documentation that states that this window handle contains a `IOleObject**` in its user data. Perhaps I'm wrong, but this has the feel of a hack that relied on an implementation detail that changed.

Comment: i updated the question

Comment: Way to less code. I used GetWindowLongPtr myself very often and there is no problem there. Try to find SetWindowLongPtr where the object is set. Try there the query to find out, if the object is already invalid. I think it is an error in the reference counting.

Comment: One thing i remembered , this code is x64 app. I have the same code in x86  app (in win 10 it doesn't crash).

Comment: @MartinSchlott: How would you use SetWindowLongPtr in this case. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I would not use it :-) IUnknown based instances are not raw pointer. You have to use AddRef before storing the pointer with SetWindowsLongPtr. If it work on  32Bit but not on 64Bit, check if you have used SetWindowLongPtr not(!) SetWindowLong as the seconds only work on 32Bit pointer.

Comment: You will need to post more code.

Comment: I mentioned that it worked on Win7 64 bit....It is win8 and win10 it crashes.

Comment: Did you register the window class, whose `GWLP_USERDATA` you are using? If you aren't, the space it not yours to use. If you are, then likely someone else in your system breaks the contract, and (ab)uses this memory. If you are registering the window class, though, use `cbWndExtra` as a safer alternative to `GWLP_USERDATA`.

Comment: I indeed register the window class and in addition posted more code

Comment: I still see no reason stated anywhere as to why you expect to find that pointer there. Did you put it there?

Comment: It would help if you noted, **which** line of code crashes, how it crashes, and all unabridged error messages you get.

Comment: The double-indirection looks suspicious to me but as others have said, without seeing how you're storing the value in the window data there's no way to know.

Comment: you have to post EmbedBrowserObject() function here, otherwise no can guess the right answer.

Comment: It crashes on the line where i call GetWindowLongPtr...Only it crashes when i perform the typecasting of *(IOIeObject **).In addition , i posted the EmbedBrowserObject

Answer (score 2):

```
SetWindowLong( hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, (LONG)ptr );
```

This is your problem. You are taking a 64-bit pointer and casting it to a 32-bit integer. This loses the upper 32 bits, so your `GetWindowLongPtr` gets a truncated pointer. You got lucky on Windows 7 because the upper bits happened to be zero so your truncation was harmless. On Windows 8, your luck ran out.

Comment: Thanks ...I think i checked this option out but i will recheck it again...Just to make sure.